# create-react-app: how to wrap for calling module?

Tags: javascript, create-react-app

I have an app with a default config of CRA. And I pass all props from HTML page using global object `Window`.

Now I want to pass all props like that:

`myApp.init("root", { ... some options ... })`

And use my app as an npm package. But official documentation and the search returned no results.

Comment: CRA is just not meant to be used to package React apps or modules as npm modules. It really is entirely focused on making client-side applications. The React documentation https://reactjs.org/community/starter-kits.html mentions libraries like nwb that can be used instead of CRA to make npm module libraries or components.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Yea, I understand it but I have legacy code with CRA and migrating to another tool isn't possible at the moment. My first solution was to create factory functions for wrap an application, but it's better to find something ready.